# Why WHOLE code is executing 3 times instead of only p1 and p2?

Tags: python, time, multiprocessing

I copy code from youtube. That guy's code works as I wish mine to. It defined 2 processes and 2 processes were executed. My whole code is executing 3 times. Why? And why doesn't he need to use `if __name__ == '__main__':`?

```
import multiprocessing
import time

start = time.perf_counter()

def do_something():
    print('Sleeping 1 second...')
    time.sleep(1)
    print('Done sleeping...')




if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=do_something)
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=do_something)
    p1.start()
    p2.start()

    p1.join()
    p2.join()

finish = time.perf_counter()

print(f'Finished in {round(finish-start, 2)} seconds(s)')
```

I expect the same to happen as the guy on youtube.

My output:

```
Finished in 0.0 seconds(s)
Sleeping 1 second...
Finished in 0.0 seconds(s)
Sleeping 1 second...
Done sleeping...
Done sleeping...
Finished in 1.08 seconds(s)

Youtube guy output:
Sleeping 1 second...
Sleeping 1 second...
Done sleeping...
Done sleeping...
Finished in 1.01 seconds(s)
```

Comment: You should post the code you wrote into your question

Comment: When you use `multiprocessing`, *ALL* top-level executable code is required to be inside a `if __name__ == '__main__':` block.  Your assignments of `p1` and `p2` violate this.

Comment: I put p1 and p2 under "if..." and nothing has changed.

Comment: You forgot to indent the last two lines.

Comment: @jasonharper Your statement is a bit of an overstatement. First, it is not particularly pertinent if the *fork* method of creating new processes is being used. Moreover, only top-level code that shouldn't be executed because of unwanted side-effects or inefficiencies arising from executing needless code or creating data not referenced by the child processes should be in such a block. But clearly there is often the need (or it is at least desirable) to have code at global scope. A trivial example: the global statement `DEBUG = True` where variable DEBUG is referenced by all processes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adrien Derouene has given a program that I am guessing addresses and corrects your problem. I am guessing only because you have not fully elaborated what your actual output is. But based on that guess, I would like to elaborate as to what the problem was to begin with and why Adrein's program corrects it:

You did not specify the platform you are in but I am guessing it is one that uses the *spawn* method to create new processes. In this case any code at global scope will get executed by all processes.

Your statements that set `start` and `finish` and print the timing are such statements at global scope. So in addition to timing how long it takes to run your two child processes in parallel, you are also timing how long it takes the Python interpreter to define all global variables, classes and functions. So I am guessing you are seeing something like the following being printed out:

```None
Finished in 0.0 seconds(s)
Sleeping 1 second...
Finished in 0.0 seconds(s)
Sleeping 1 second...
Done sleeping...
Done sleeping...
Finished in 1.15 seconds(s)
```

Strictly speaking, the child process has no need to see the `import multiprocessing` statement, so even this could be moved as follows:

```py
import time

def do_something():
    print('Sleeping 1 second...')
    time.sleep(1)
    print('Done sleeping...')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import multiprocessing

    start = time.perf_counter()

    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=do_something)
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=do_something)
    p1.start()
    p2.start()

    p1.join()
    p2.join()

    finish = time.perf_counter()

    print(f'Finished in {round(finish-start, 2)} seconds(s)')
```

Prints:

```None
Sleeping 1 second...
Sleeping 1 second...
Done sleeping...
Done sleeping...
Finished in 1.14 seconds(s)
```

So, your original program was not strictly running *all* executable code 3 times, but rather just the timings and printing.

**Note also that both the main processes need to use `time` functions and that is why this is one global statement that should not be placed within a `if __name__ == '__main__':` block.**

Answer (score 0):

Using :

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

You have to have all your executing code inside it:

```
import multiprocessing
import time

def do_something():
    print('Sleeping 1 second...')
    time.sleep(1)
    print('Done sleeping...')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = time.perf_counter()

    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=do_something)
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=do_something)
    p1.start()
    p2.start()

    p1.join()
    p2.join()

    finish = time.perf_counter()

    print(f'Finished in {round(finish-start, 2)} seconds(s)')
```